# Regular Expression : How to get the value in curly brace except square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get only "`Callout`" value in below string using regex in Javascript.

```
str = "aaa {Callout [apple]} bbbb";
```

Comment: This needs a lot more elaboration. What have you tried ? Where did you fail ? What should be matched when you have `aaa {Callout [apple] Callin} bbbb` ? What about `aaa { {ccc, Callout} ddd [apple] Callin} bbbb`. I'm voting to close this question

Comment: Don't worry about other scenario. I'm looking only for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple in my opinion. If you want the first match in the string access it by `result[0]`..

```
var string = "asdfadsfsad {Callout1 [callout1]} dasdfsadf {Callout2 [callout2]} ccc]";
var result = string.match(/[^{]+(?=\[)/g);
console.log(result[0]); // => "Callout1 "
```

For all matches just access `result` directly.

```
console.log(result); // => [ 'Callout1 ', 'Callout2 ' ]
```

Regular expression:

```
[^{]+          any character except: '{' (1 or more times)
 (?=           look ahead to see if there is:
  \[           '['
 )             end of look-ahead
```

Comment: This code What I want exactly... You made my weekend is happy... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookahead and group matching:

```
\{(\w+)(?=\b)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[See Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2HG3JWsIcafzDoHt)

JS code:

```
var re = new RegExp(/\{(\w+)(?=\b)/);
var m = re.exec("aaa {Callout [apple]} bbbb");
alert(m[1]);
```

Comment: Displaying output with curly brace from beginning. But I don't want initial curly brace in output.

Comment: @RanjitSachin it will not be in the output if you'll call only the matched group: see JS code example above

Comment: Oops.. I'm trying like below: 
var str = "asdfadsfsad {Callout [callout1]} dasdfsadf  {Callout [callout2]} ccc]"; 
var patt= /\{(\w+)(?=\b)/g; 
var result = str.match(patt);
alert(result);

Comment: @RanjitSachin but I specifically wrote: "see JS code example **above**" - so why are you trying the one below ? :p

Comment: Please can you correct me What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @RanjitSachin yes, you're printing `alert(result)` instead of `alert(result[1])`. Didn't you see the code snippet I added to my answer ?

Comment: I agree. But it will fail in if multiple text scenario: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ranjitsachin/sd4c2/

Comment: @RanjitSachin why do you insist on not looking at the code snippet I posted ? you should remove the `/g` flag from the pattern: http://jsfiddle.net/sd4c2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{(.*?)\[
```

## [Regex Demo](http://rubular.com/r/X2PXm4UOKG)

```
var myString = "asdfadsfsad {Callout [callout1]} dasdfsadf {Callout [callout2]} ccc]";
var myRegexp = /{(.*?)\[/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);
```

## [Working JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sdL2/33/)